# tabhost or layout is pushing admob banner below screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

i have an app that uses tabs to show different content..... there is an admob banner below the tabs that should never move..... it should be locked to the bottom of the screen...........

most of the content is shown using activity_main.xml which includes content_main.xml using  and i have never had a problem with the layout before..... everything fit fine.....

here is what the layout is SUPPOSE to look like....
[image: real layout]

i recently added a new tab and java file called bpm counter.... 
the bpm counter tab has its own layout and doesn't use activity_main.xml or the content_main.xml instead it uses its own activity_main2.xml and everything is sort of working but here is the problem....

when i open the app everything looks normal like it always has with the banner at the bottom of the page.... however when i click the bpm counter tab the admob banner moves down and goes half way of the screen....... then when i try to go back to any other tab the banner moves wayyy up and i get a white space below the admob banner

you can see the problem of the banner moving down when i visit the bpm tab here
[image: problem 1]

and then when i try to go back to the home page or any other tab the banner moves way up... as you can see in the photo below
[image: problem 2]

i have tried changing match_parent and fill_parent and have tried a lot of tweak in the layout but i can not figure out what i am doing wrong and i am about to bang my head off a wall.... any help would be wonderful and appreciated!

here are my .xml layout files

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.raptools.app.raptools.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

here is my content_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.raptools.app.raptools.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4075500144464557/8371434413"/>

<WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/homepageimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/homepageimage"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comingimage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/comingsoon"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

those two layout files were working fine until i tried to add the new bpm counter tab......

here is the activity_main2.xml that is used for the bpm counter java

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.raptools.app.raptools.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorRemoveAds"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".BpmCounter">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/bpm"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/initial_bpm_value"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tapButtonView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="@string/tap"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="@string/reset_instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

i hope i have explained in enough detail and any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1):

i ended up staring at the three codes i posted above for a long time and decided to copy the frame from activity_main.xml pasted it in the activity_main2.xml and removed the linear layout and made sure to include android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and i managed to get it working!

here is the working code incase anyone has this problem ever

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.raptools.app.raptools.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/appView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/transitioning_background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".BpmCounter">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/bpm"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bpmTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bpmLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/initial_bpm_value"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="70sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tapButtonView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:text="@string/tap"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instructionalLabelTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:text="@string/reset_instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```